# How to get list item that was selected in previous Activity passed on to next Activity and there make list item selected

Tags: android, listview, actionbarsherlock, android-listfragment, slidingmenu

I have a ListFragment, that gets created / attched in many activities, It has a list view, which shows Activity names 
Ex: "Activity A" 
    "Activity B"
    "Activity C"...
tapping on those item navigates the user to tapped Activity. Also I am using Sliding-Menu library to show the List Fragment.

Now Issues is:

When user opens Sliding menu in "Activity B" taps on sliding menu list item "Activity A" while in "Activity B", then user navigates to Activity A, but what I want is when user opens the Sliding Menu in "Activity A", He should see in Sliding Menu, that List Item for "Activity A" is already selected.

Let me know how this can be achieved.